# LSA-SAF data reprojection with GDAL and R

Tags: gdal, r, coordinate-system, proj

The Land Surface Analysis Satellite Applications Facility
([LSA SAF](http://landsaf.meteo.pt/)) distributes several products
derived from the EUMETSAT satellites data. I am working with `R` to read and process the data (the
file of this example is available from the
[Static Auxiliary Data page](https://landsaf.meteo.pt/auxiliarDataFiles.jsp)
of the LSA-SAF service.)

```
library(rgdal)
library(raster)

r <- raster("HDF5_LSASAF_USGS_DEM_Euro.hdf")
```

Although the file is read correctly, the projection info is missing.

```
> r
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 651, 1701, 1107351  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent      : 0, 1701, 0, 651  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : NA 
data source : /home/oscar/temp/HDF5_LSASAF_USGS_DEM_Euro.hdf 
names       : HDF5_LSASAF_USGS_DEM_Euro 
values      : -32768, 32767  (min, max)
```

If I use `gdalsrsinfo` to parse the file and obtain the
projection, I get `ERROR 1: ERROR - failed to load SRS definition
from ...` which is more or less the same if I use `GDALspatialRef`
in `R`:

```
> GDALSpatialRef('HDF5_LSASAF_USGS_DEM_Euro.hdf')
[1] ""
```

[As far as I know](http://landsaf.meteo.pt/jforum/posts/list/7.page) these files use the
[GEOS projection](http://www.remotesensing.org/geotiff/proj_list/geos.html).
However, if I set this PROJ.4 string and the file is transformed
to a latitude-longitude projection, the results are erroneous
(look at the extent of the `projectExtent` output):

```
projection(r) <- CRS("+proj=geos +lon_0=0 +h=35785831 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs ")

> projectExtent(r, CRS(projLL))
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 651, 1701, 1107351  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 8.983153e-06, 9.043695e-06  (x, y)
extent      : 0, 0.01528034, 0, 0.005887445  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

It seems that the LSA-SAF data
[are not yet geo-corrected](http://marswiki.jrc.ec.europa.eu/agri4castwiki/index.php/MSG-SEVIRI#Geometric_corrections)
and the images are expressed in the "raw" Column-Row system, so
this could be the root of the problem. There are
[Latitude and Longitude static files](https://landsaf.meteo.pt/auxiliarDataFiles.jsp)
which could be used for remapping the rasters. However, I would
like to use a more direct approach with a correct PROJ.4 string
and a projection transform with `gdalwarp` or `rgdal::spTransform`
in `R`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found a solution using the
[Latitude and Longitude static files](https://landsaf.ipma.pt/en/community/auxiliarydata/)
together with the DEM raster:

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)

dem <- raster("HDF5_LSASAF_USGS_DEM_Euro.hdf")
lat <- raster("HDF5_LSASAF_MSG_LAT_Euro_4bytesPrecision.hdf")
lon <- raster("HDF5_LSASAF_MSG_LON_Euro_4bytesPrecision.hdf")

## Only the numeric content is needed
dem <- dem[]
## Scale lat and long values
lat <- lat[]/10000
lon <- lon[]/10000

## It is important to exclude 90º angles to avoid problems
## with reprojection. Besides, I reduce the data to a region
valid <- (lon < 10  & lon > -10) & (lat < 50 & lat > 30)
lat <- lat[valid]
lon <- lon[valid]
dem <- dem[valid]
dem[dem<0] <- NA
```

I define an `SpatialPointsDataFrame` object (irregularly spaced
points) using the latitude and longitude values as the
coordinates, the DEM file as the data, and with the long/lat
projection.

```
projLL <- CRS('+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0')
ll <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(cbind(lon, lat), data=data.frame(dem),
                             proj4string=projLL)
```

Next, I reproject this `SpatialPointsDataFrame` to the GEOS
projection with `spTransform`.

```
projGeos <- CRS("+proj=geos +lon_0=0 +h=35785831 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs ")
xy <- spTransform(ll, projGeos)
```

Finally, I define an `SpatialPixelsDataFrame` (a regular grid)
with the new coordinates, which can be easily converted to a
`RasterLayer` object.

```
demGrid <- SpatialPixelsDataFrame(xy, data.frame(dem), tolerance=0.311898)
dem <- raster(demGrid)

> dem
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 360, 592, 213120  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 2986.185, 2992.444  (x, y)
extent      : -883596.1, 884225.5, 3470127, 4547407  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=geos +lon_0=0 +h=35785831 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
data source : in memory
names       : dem 
values      : 0, 3866  (min, max)
```

[image: dem with spplot]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your test example is not online anymore, so I took a gobal Land-Sea-Temperature sample from ftp://landsaf.ipma.pt/pub/Example_of_Product/

As mentioned in my answer to [Transforming geostationary satellite image to lon/lat](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/192721/transforming-geostationary-satellite-image-to-lon-lat), the size of global geos reprojected files is 3712x3712 pixels (3-km-resolution), but the actual data array is smaller. GDAL knows the GEOS projection, but has a different resolution using meters, depending on the satellite height above the ellipsoid. But you can add the proper extent expected by GDAL, and then reproject to WGS84 with:

```
gdal_translate -a_srs "+proj=geos +h=35785831 +a=6378169 +b=6356583.8 +no_defs" -a_ullr -5568000 5568000 5568000 -5568000 HDF5:"HDF5_LSASAF.hdf"://LST temp.tif
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 -wo SOURCE_EXTRA=100 temp.tif LSASAF.tif
```

to get this picture:

[image]