# Transforming geostationary satellite image to lon/lat

Tags: raster, gdal, r, proj, hdf

The ICARE Data and Services Center distributes the SEV_AERUS-AEROSOL-D3 product in HDF5 format (http://www.icare.univ-lille1.fr/archive/?dir=GEO/MSG+0000/SEV_AERUS-AEROSOL-D3.v1.03/).

The main component of the HDF file is a **3712 x 3712 matrix**, which represents measurements on a geostationary view of the earth, such as in the following image:

[image]

In **R**, I am able to read the latter into a matrix object named `m` using the `h5` package:

```
library(h5)
setwd("/home/michael/Dropbox/BGU/Alex/HDF5")
filename = "SEV_AERUS-AEROSOL-D3_2005-01-01_V1-03.h5"
h = h5file(filename)
m = h["ANGS_06_16"][]
```

Here are the matrix dimensions:

```
dim(m)
## [1] 3712 3712
```

And, for example, these are the values in the first 1-5 rows/columns:

```
m[1:5, 1:5]
##        [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]
## [1,] -32768 -32768 -32768 -32768 -32768
## [2,] -32768 -32768 -32768 -32768 -32768
## [3,] -32768 -32768 -32768 -32768 -32768
## [4,] -32768 -32768 -32768 -32768 -32768
## [5,] -32768 -32768 -32768 -32768 -32768
```

The HDF5 file also provides metadata with the lon/lat of two corners for the bounding box of `m` (below) as well as the projection type (specified simply as "GEOS"). Here is a reproduction of the bounding box coordinates exactly as given in the metadata:

```
library(raster)
ext = new("Extent"
          , xmin = -75.1001529854046
          , xmax = 75.1001529854046
          , ymin = -77.9875583358503
          , ymax = 77.9875583358503
)
ext
## class       : Extent 
## xmin        : -75.10015 
## xmax        : 75.10015 
## ymin        : -77.98756 
## ymax        : 77.98756
```

The problem is that I need to find out the spatial location of each measurement in the matrix. In order to do that, the matrix needs to be converted into a point layer with lon/lat coordinates for each pixel.

My idea was:

1. Convert the latter bounding box coordinates of `m` to "GEOS" projection coordinates.
2. Convert `m` to a `RasterLayer` object, using the "GEOS" projection bounding box and a "GEOS" CRS definition.
3. Transform the resulting `RasterLayer` to a point layer.
4. Reproject the point layer to lon/lat.

Unfortunately, I am stuck in step (1). For example, the following code takes the Southernmonst/Westernmost corner in order to calculate its coordinates in the "GEOS" system:

```
ext = data.frame(x = ext[1], y = ext[3])
ext
##           x         y
## 1 -75.10015 -77.98756
coordinates(ext) = ~ x + y
proj4string(ext) = '+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0'
spTransform(ext, "+proj=geos +lon_0=0 +h=35785831 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")
```

The last expression gives the following error message:

```
Error in spTransform(x, CRS(CRSobj), ...) : 
error in pj_transform: tolerance condition error
```

In other words, the (-75.10015, -77.98756) point can't be converted from lon/lat to "GEOS". I also tried different variations of the "GEOS" PROJ.4 string, none worked. The "tolerance condition error" is apparently a general PROJ.4 issue, since I also get the same error when trying to reproject the (-75.10015, -77.98756) point from lon/lat to "GEOS" using `pyproj` in **Python**, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264508/how-to-get-latitude-and-longitute-for-a-pixel-of-a-eumetsat-image-using-python).

When using coordinates closer to the equator, such as (10,20), the code works fine (no "tolerance condition error"). But this doesn't help, since I can't subset the `m` matrix without knowing the new bounding box coordinates.

Another option could have been translating the matrix to lon/lat using **Longitute/Latitude static files**, as suggested [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64502/lsa-saf-data-reprojection-with-gdal-and-r/65439#65439). However I couldn't find any such files matching the 3712 x 3712 dimensions.

Does anyone have experience with going from a 3712 x 3712 matrix representing a geostationary satellite image to a point layer in lon/lat? Are there any **static files** providing predetermined lon/lat values of each cell in such a grid?

Comment: I suggst you to use python. Piproj.
First you have to transform lines and columns in the image intermediate coordinates as explained. Or maybe your file contain it : search Gdal array.... and gdal projection string inside the file........

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your attempt is designed to fail. If you look at the image, you see the data arranged as a circle, with black triangles in the corners of the square, where the satellite view goes right into orbit. In your test data, you see only NODATA -32768 for those parts of the image.

The extent is between +/-75 and +/- 78, but these values are only reached in the middle of the egdes. So you can not reproject those black triangles to Earth surface coordinates.

---

**UPDATE**

The Metadata of the HDF file reveals some mysteries:

```
Altitude=42164 
Ancillary_Files=MSG+0000.3km.lat
```

So the satellite height is the same as mentioned in http://geotiff.maptools.org/proj_list/geos.html, and I assume they took the same ellipsoid (not exactly WGS84).

With the help of http://www.cgms-info.org/documents/pdf_cgms_03.pdf and http://publications.jrc.ec.europa.eu/repository/bitstream/JRC52438/combal_noel_msg_final.pdf, I found that the size of 3712px is not the real extent covered by the data. The size provides a scanning angle of the satellite of about +/-8.915 degree, but the angle that was used is smaller.

Proj.4 calculates the extent by multiplying the satellite's scanning angle by the height above ground (see http://proj4.org/projections/geos.html). So with a bit of try, an extent of +/- 5568000m (3712*3000m/2 or 8.915*pi()/180*35785831m) fits to the 3712px used in the 3-km-resolution hdf.

So the correct translation commands are:

```
gdal_translate -a_srs "+proj=geos +h=35785831 +a=6378169 +b=6356583.8 +no_defs" -a_ullr -5568000 5568000 5568000 -5568000 HDF5:"SEV_AERUS-AEROSOL-D3_2006-01-01_V1-03.h5"://ANGS_06_16 temp.tif
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 -wo SOURCE_EXTRA=100 temp.tif output.tif
```

And the result looks good:

[image]

As an alternative, you can take the lat and lon subdatasets from http://www.icare.univ-lille1.fr/archive/?dir=GEO/STATIC/ in file MSG+0000.3km.hdf

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer. The explanation makes sense: if the bounding box corners are outside of the "GEOS" grid then there's no way I can find their coordinates in that CRS.

The `gdalwarp` command also works, but doesn't seem to find the right transformation either. The resulting image looks exacly like the origin, only with a different bounding box, in lon/lat:

0.0000000000000000,0.0000000010817455 0.0000089843362493,0.0000090436947705

which is clearly incorrect...

Comment: See my extended answer.

Comment: I don't yet understand the required geometric calculation to get exact geo-referencing with this method, so not sure I am going to use it over the subsetting method (unless I must get data for an area that was not predefined in the static files). But in principle this is the result I wanted, so I'm marking it as the right answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: Great! Thank you for the update, this is what I was looking for.

Comment: I'd like to ask the rationale behind the +/- 5568000m value? I'm sure it's obvious but I can't find any reference to it?

Comment: @tda it is just the extent of 3712 px with 3km cell size resolution, as I wrote in my answer.

Comment: I understand now - you're dividing the resolution by two so confused me slightly. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @tda only half the size because the origin is in the middle, so the extent is +/-.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE:

The above-mentioned approach by Oscar Perpiñán found [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64502/lsa-saf-data-reprojection-with-gdal-and-r/65439#65439) seems to work, if I only take a subset of the matrix the way Oscar did.

For that to work I needed to know the subset boundaries and the **static files**, both available online for a few regions (such as North Africa).

```
m = m[700:1850, 1240:3450, drop = FALSE]

lon = raster("NAFR_LON.img")
lat = raster("NAFR_LAT.img")

lat <- lat[]
lon <- lon[]

projLL <- CRS('+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0')
ll <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(cbind(lon, lat), data=data.frame(as.vector(m)),
                             proj4string=projLL)

writeOGR(ll, ".", "output_eu", driver = "ESRI Shapefile", overwrite_layer = TRUE)
```

This is what the resulting layer looks like in QGIS:

[image]

Nevertheless, if there is a way to transform the entire matrix, as asked in the original question, I'll be happy to learn about it...

UPDATE: User [AndreJ](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/9159/andrej) provides the complete solution, above.