# HRV Geostationary Projection GDAL

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, wgs84

Following guidance from another geos. question posted on here ([Transforming geostationary satellite image to lon/lat](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/192721/transforming-geostationary-satellite-image-to-lon-lat)) I'm attempting to project my data to WGS 84. However my data is HRV from MSG. This is higher resolution (1 km) and covers North Africa/Europe.

gdalinfo "my_data.nc":

```
Driver: netCDF/Network Common Data Format
Files: my_data.nc
Size is 5568, 2880
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["unnamed",
    BASEGEOGCRS["unknown",
        DATUM["unnamed",
            ELLIPSOID["Spheroid",6378169,295.488065897014,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                    ID["EPSG",9001]]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                ID["EPSG",9122]]]],
    CONVERSION["unnamed",
        METHOD["Geostationary Satellite (Sweep Y)"],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Satellite Height",35785832,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["easting",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]],
        AXIS["northing",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (-0.052723478849088,0.155683081920578)
Pixel Size = (0.000027947774241,-0.000027947774795)
Metadata:
  data#add_offset=0.5189243
  data#comment=Visible channel top of atmosphere reflectance, normalized using the solar zenith angle, central wavelength of  0.75 microns, Geostationary projection
  data#coordinates=time y x
  data#grid_mapping=geostationary
  data#keywords=Visible, reflectance, MSG, SEVIRI
  data#long_name=toa_bidirectional_reflectance
  data#scale_factor=1.4681713e-05
  data#standard_name=toa_bidirectional_reflectance
  data#units=1
  data#_FillValue=-32768
  geostationary#false_easting=0
  geostationary#false_northing=0
  geostationary#grid_mapping_name=geostationary
  geostationary#latitude_of_projection_origin=0
  geostationary#longitude_of_projection_origin=0
  geostationary#perspective_point_height=35785832
  geostationary#semi_major_axis=6378169
  geostationary#semi_minor_axis=6356583.800000001
  geostationary#sweep_angle_axis=y
  NC_GLOBAL#acknowledgement=EUMETSAT
  NC_GLOBAL#Conventions=CF-1.7
  NC_GLOBAL#history=Created: 2020-03-02T10:03:00Z
  NC_GLOBAL#instrument=SEVIRI
  NC_GLOBAL#platform=MSG
  NC_GLOBAL#standard_name_vocabulary=CF Standard Name Table v27
  NC_GLOBAL#title=TOA reflectance
  x#axis=X
  x#long_name=Projection x coordinate in radians
  x#standard_name=projection_x_coordinate
  x#units=
  y#axis=Y
  y#long_name=Projection y coordinate in radians
  y#standard_name=projection_y_coordinate
  y#units=
Subdatasets:
  SUBDATASET_1_NAME=NETCDF:"my_data.nc":data
  SUBDATASET_1_DESC=[2880x5568] toa_bidirectional_reflectance (16-bit integer)
Geolocation:
  LINE_OFFSET=0
  LINE_STEP=1
  PIXEL_OFFSET=0
  PIXEL_STEP=1
  SRS=GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AXIS["Latitude",NORTH],AXIS["Longitude",EAST],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
  X_BAND=1
  X_DATASET=NETCDF:"my_data.nc":x
  Y_BAND=1
  Y_DATASET=NETCDF:"my_data.nc":y
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  -0.0527235,   0.1556831) (  0d 0' 0.00"W,  0d 0' 0.01"N)
Lower Left  (  -0.0527235,   0.0751935) (  0d 0' 0.00"W,  0d 0' 0.00"N)
Upper Right (   0.1028897,   0.1556831) (  0d 0' 0.00"E,  0d 0' 0.01"N)
Lower Right (   0.1028897,   0.0751935) (  0d 0' 0.00"E,  0d 0' 0.00"N)
Center      (   0.0250831,   0.1154383) (  0d 0' 0.00"E,  0d 0' 0.00"N)
Band 1 Block=1856x960 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Undefined
  NoData Value=-32768
  Unit Type: 1
  Offset: 0.518924295902252,   Scale:1.46817128552357e-05
  Metadata:
    add_offset=0.5189243
    comment=Visible channel top of atmosphere reflectance, normalized using the solar zenith angle, central wavelength of  0.75 microns, Geostationary projection
    coordinates=time y x
    grid_mapping=geostationary
    keywords=Visible, reflectance, MSG, SEVIRI
    long_name=toa_bidirectional_reflectance
    NETCDF_VARNAME=data
    scale_factor=1.4681713e-05
    standard_name=toa_bidirectional_reflectance
    units=1
    _FillValue=-32768
```

Using the same methods as metioned above these are my commands:

```
gdal_translate -ot float32 -unscale -CO COMPRESS=deflate -a_srs "+proj=geos +lon_0=0 +h=35785832 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378169 +b=6356583.8 +rf=295.488065897014 +units=m +no_defs" -a_ullr -2784000 1440000 2784000 -1440000 NETCDF:"mydata.nc":data par_disk.tiff

gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 -wo SOURCE_EXTRA=100 par_disk.tiff par_disk_WGS84.tiff
```

I have used "-2784000 1440000 2784000 -1440000" as my data is 5568x2880 and the resolution is 1 km ie. 5568000/2 and 2880000/2.

The issue is the GeoTiff appears over the Equator:

[image: image in incorrect position]

Any ideas why this is happening?